# Where and how to post UX review requests

Tags: discussion

I'd like to get feedback on the UX of various products ("how would you improve this site's UX?"). Are such open-ended questions anathema in this community?

What sites do we refer users to who post critique requests?

Answer (score 3):

Our second close reason says the following:

> Questions about **Site Reviews** are off-topic because questions here are
>   expected to be relevant for a variety of people in the same situation.
>   Reviewing a site, flow or interface only helps one person at a
>   specific time. Instead try to ask a focused question about a
>   particular aspect of the design that solicits solutions, not opinions.

From the Help Center, we have the page [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) which also tells us to avoid open-ended questions.

So no, you can't ask **Site Review** questions nor **open-ended** question.

Comment: Do you know of sites where users can post critique requests?